# angularJS How can I ignore certain HTML tags?

Tags: html, angularjs, tags

I got this error because one of the users added in his post `<3`

> Error: [$sanitize:badparse] The sanitizer was unable to parse the following block of html: <3

I wrote code that `ng-bind-html ="Detail.details"`

I want him to be taken only `<a>` tag and tag `<br />`

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: I <3 such bug reports.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create filter which will sanitize your html.

I used in it strip_tags function 
http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/

```
angular.module('filters', []).factory('truncate', function () {
    return function strip_tags(input, allowed) {
      allowed = (((allowed || '') + '')
        .toLowerCase()
        .match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || [])
        .join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
      var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
        commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
      return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '')
        .replace(tags, function($0, $1) {
          return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
        });
    }
});
```

controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['filters'])
.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'truncate', '$sce', function($scope, truncate, $sce){
  $scope.text="";

  $scope.$watch('text', function(){
    $scope.sanitized = $sce.trustAsHtml(truncate($scope.text, '<a><br>'));
  });
}]);
```

view:

```
<div ng-bind-html="sanitized"></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qOuvpSMvooC6jR0HxCNT?p=preview

Comment: is ti possible to not replace wrong tags but display them?
Example, in your plunker, insteand of not having <b> tags, just display <b>Bold sanitized</b>?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and fixed it by using `$sce.trustAsHtml`, see this

```
$scope.body = $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlBody);

// In html
<div ng-bind-html="body">body</div>
```

It fix the issue

Comment: I think this is a bad idea. You are then bypassing the ngSanitize security checks. So you may open you application to HTML injection attacks.

Comment: Look I am not using `ng-bind-html-unsafe` which is depricated, you cannot use `ng-bind-html` without `ngSanitize`. So there is no security issue.

Answer (score 3):

To preserve existing `ng-bind-html` behaviour without crashing you can catch the `$sanitize:badparse` exception.

The `ngBindHtml` [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) internally uses the `ngSanitize` [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize). Inject `$sanitize` into your controller and catch it.

The advantage of this versus the `$sce.trustAsHtml` methods is that `$sanitize` does not introduce any potential security holes (eg. javascript injection).

Controller (inject `$sanitize`):

```
$scope.clean = function (string) {
    $scope.clean = function(string) {
        try {
            return $sanitize(string);
        } catch(e) {
            return;
        }
    };
};
```

This method could be improved with a cache of the last known good value.

View:

```
<div ng-bind-html="clean(body)"></div>
```