# How to trace: "The sanitizer was unable to parse the following block of html: <32"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
Error: [$sanitize:badparse] The sanitizer was unable to parse the following block of html: <32
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$sanitize/badparse?p0=%3C32
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:79:12
    at htmlParser (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-sanitize.js?body=1:311:13)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-sanitize.js?body=1:144:7
    at getTrusted (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:13336:16)
    at Object.sce.(anonymous function) [as getTrustedHtml] (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:14017:16)
    at Object.ngBindHtmlWatchAction (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:18146:25)
    at Object.applyFunction [as fn] (<anonymous>:778:50)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12396:29)
    at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12661:24)
```

I am aware that it is because of the following issue: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$sanitize/badparse?p0=%3C32

> "This error occurs when the HTML string passed to '$sanitize' can't be
>   parsed by the sanitizer. The error contains part of the html string
>   that can't be parsed.
>
> The parser is more strict than a typical browser parser, so it's
>   possible that some obscure input would produce this error despite the
>   string being recognized as valid HTML by a browser."

My question is: how to trace this problem? From the stack trace alone, none of them refers to my code. Is there any tools which can help tracing this issue?

Comment: Not exact what you are looking for,
but this may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533491/angularjs-how-can-i-ignore-certain-html-tags

Comment: Have you found the cause? In my case it was invalid html input. E.g. "Some<XT[2]>-<AAC[9]>". The parser thought this are html tags.
In your case "<32" is an invalid tag name as well.

Comment: Hope this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533491/angularjs-how-can-i-ignore-certain-html-tags help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Chrome Developer Tools (CDT) to catch **caught** JS exceptions (check "Pause on Caught Exceptions" checkbox in CDT). That may give you more information about your issue.

See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

[image: Chrome debugger]

Comment: This does not actually help to find the source of the issues, because, as the OP states, "From the stack trace alone, none of them refers to my code." Unless you are suggesting that this is a bug in AngularJS (and I think it's clear it's not), then debugging AngularJS is not going to tack down the source of the issue. It's not anywhere in the stack.