# The sanitizer was unable to parse the following block of html: <br style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px;\"/>

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-bind-html

The follows is my code in the template:

`<div ng-bind-html="product.qtxx"></div>`

But I got error maybe because the data in the json contains html codes like "`<br style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px;\"/>`", and ionic throws error:

```
Error: [$sanitize:badparse] The sanitizer was unable to parse the following block of html: <br style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px;\"/>blabla
```

I cant solve this problem, maybe it's because the double quotation marks`""` in the html affects the json syntax?
Is it possible to solve this?

Comment: i think this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533491/angularjs-how-can-i-ignore-certain-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

Add a scope method like this:

```
$scope.sanitizeMe = function(text) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
};
```

and use that in your view:

```
<div ng-bind-html="sanitizeMe(product.qtxx)"></div>
```

And may be you need to parse your HTML:

```
<br style=\“margin: 0px; padding: 0px;\”/>
```

(not sure, you have special characters as well like invalid double quotes `””` instead of `""`)

to

```
<br style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" />
```

Comment: trustAsHtml bypasses sanitization. `sanitizeMe` doesn't sanitize, but allows unsanitized html into your page. See [$sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)